# Question about communication between activity and fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interface, fragment

I ask me a question about the communication between an activity and a fragment. In my situation, i have only one activity and multiple fragments.
I have 2 possibilites:

- Use interface (long)
- Just use getActivity(or activity) with a cast to the activity: `(activity as MainActivity)."variable"`

Logically the second in my situation is the best but there is no problem with this solution ?

Comment: No there is normally no Problem with the 2nd solution, there is only a very small window when a Fragment is attached where getactivity can return null, but this shouldnt be a Problem in almost every case where you use getactivity

Comment: I would start using `ViewModel` in that case. Interfaces are alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd one might seem easier to implement for sure. But First one is more loosely coupled, so Maintenance friendly and many other benefits.

Using interface in this regard is better choice because it follows Observer design pattern, which is well tested, well understood. Also type casting to specific activity makes fragment strongly coupled with activity, which is not a good design. In order to use that fragment anywhere else, you have to update the type casting section every time, which also hampers reusability and also violate Open-closed Principle of SOLID.